# Sinch Instant Messaging, message is not received when user is online

Tags: ios, objective-c, instant-messaging, sinch

Sinch SDK on iOS, suddenly the messaging has broken. Even when the recipient is online the message is sent through Push Notification. This used to work fine but after I logged in to my app with different users (on the same device) this stopped working.
This is getting very frustrating, I would appreciate if you could help me, or if you could suggest an alternative to Sinch for Instant Messaging.

Thanks

**Edit - Code**

in AppDelegate

```
if (!_sinchClient)
{
    _sinchClient = [Sinch clientWithApplicationKey:SINCH_APPLICATION_KEY
                                 applicationSecret:SINCH_APPLICATION_SECRET
                                   environmentHost:SINCH_ENVIRONMENT_HOST
                                            userId:backendless.userService.currentUser.objectId];

    _sinchClient.delegate = self;
   [_sinchClient setSupportPushNotifications:YES];
   [_sinchClient setSupportMessaging:YES];
   [_sinchClient start];
}
```

in the chat view controller

```
_sinchMessageClient = [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).sinchClient messageClient];
_sinchMessageClient.delegate = self;
```

and in the same controller for sending the message

```
SINOutgoingMessage *sinMessage = [SINOutgoingMessage messageWithRecipient:connectedUser.objectId text:message.text];
[_sinchMessageClient sendMessage:sinMessage];
```

(Code is simplified for display purposes)

There are no logout functionalities, as none was mentioned in the documentation - or have I missed something?

Comment: CAn you share your login and logout code.

Comment: @cjensen edited the post with the code, thanks

Comment: So when you say stoped working, what do you mean? Are you handling the push your self? IF you want us to handle it you should change [_sinchClient setSupportPushNotifications:YES]; to [_sinchClient setSupportManagedPush:YES]; and upload a certficate, also if you log out you shoud do a unregisterPushData

Comment: @cjensen thanks for your reply, I mean that it does not send message when the the receiving user is online (in the chat) and send the message as a push notification. I am handling the push myself and there are no issues with that.

Comment: How to you logout form the app?